# Computing $a_{2^n}-a_{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$, then how

$$
a_{2^n}-a_{2^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+1}+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}-1}+\frac{1}{2^n}
$$
I do not understand this!

Comment: Write down several differences $a_{4}-a_{2}, \, a_{8}-a_{4}, \, a_{16}-a_{8}, \ldots $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just canceling terms.

For example, when $n=3$,

$$a_{2^3}-a_{2^2}=a_8-a_4=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{4+1}+\frac{1}{4+2}+\frac{1}{4+3}+\frac{1}{8}$$

When $n=4$,

$$a_{2^4}-a_{2^3}=a_{16}-a_8=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}+\cdots+\frac{1}{16}=\frac{1}{8+1}+\frac{1}{8+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{8+7}+\frac{1}{16}$$